# Basic pointer arithmetic for arrays

Tags: pointers

What would be the value of array and p after executing

```
int array[] = {1,2,3}, *p = array;

a. *p++;
b. (*p)++;
c. *p++; (*p)++
```

I know the answer is

```
a) array = {1,2,3} and *p = 2 
b) array = {2,2,3} and *p = 2
c) array = {1,3,3} and *p = 3
```

but I just don't understand how. And explanation would be great!

Comment: @mclaassen: I don't think that was the intent.  The question specifically asks for the value of `p`.  I think that was an incorrect edit...  I think he wants `p = array+1` and similar there.

Comment: Well it matches the results. I think he was clearly interested in the value pointed to by p and not the memory address itself.

Comment: I'm... not so sure, since the third element of the second array switched to `2` and back.  Though I think that was a typo.  I begin to think you're correct.

Comment: Any way you cut it, the shown answer for `b` is wrong.

Comment: The questions states "I know the answer is.." so the question makes a lot more sense if you update it so that the answer really is what is shown.

Comment: What is the answer for b? I don't get it. Oh it is {2,2,2}

Comment: @user3657269 The answer should be {2,2,3}. I updated your question with the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

p initially points to the first element of the array, so

- a. Move the pointer to point to the next element, which is 2.
- b. Dereference p, which is 1, then increase it by 1, which becomes 2.
- c. The first part is same as a. so the pointer points to the second element, then you dereference it, you get 2, and increase it by 1, you get 3.